# when does DataContractJsonSerializer include the type information?

Tags: .net, wcf, json, serialization

I noticed that with the DataContractJsonSerializer the serialized JSON string sometimes include the type information in the form of

```
{"__type":"MyClass:#MyNamespace", ... }
```

based on my observations it seems to only do this when it's serializing a base type but a **known** sub type is passed instead which makes sense, but I haven't found any official documentations to confirm this or indeed anyway to force the serializer to consistently exhibit this behaviour whenever it encounters a custom type.

Can anyone confirm if my observations are correct? Better yet, if you know of a way to instruct the serializer to always serialize the type information for custom types, if this is at all possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, you CAN force the serializer to always consistently emit __type information.

If you are using the serializer standalone, use the `constructor overload` that takes the "alwaysEmitTypeInformation" argument. Pass in true.

If you are using DataContractJsonSerializerOperationBehavior, set the same property on that attribute to true. I believe you can also do it via config.

Finally, see the section "When Are Type Hints Emitted" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx for a more detailed explanation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: great! that's exactly what I was looking for, didn't even realise one of the constructor overloads let you specify whether to always emit type information, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes thanks. I was banging my head at how I could get JSON to serialize to the full type when a base type is passed and I saw this. It makes it much easier than some hacky solution I could come up with.