# Serialize C# object, want to deserialize to an interface

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, protobuf-net

I want to send instruction objects between a server and a client.  I want to be able to serialize an implementation of an interface and then, when I deserialize it, I want to deserialize it to the generic interface type (while it maintains the actual type it was serialized as).

I tried doing this with the default BinarySerializer but I encountered problems when sending the information across the wire.

I also tried using Protobuf to serialize but with Protobuf you must know the fully qualified type of the object you want to deserialize to.  IE:

```
public interface IExample
{
     void foo();
}
public class Implementation : IExample
{
     void foo() { Console.WriteLine("This is an implementation!"); }
}
```

can only be deserialized with:

```
Serializer.Deserialize<Implementation>(stream);
```

which defeats the point of polymorphism.

Is there a serialization library I can use where the caller of the deserialize method doesn't need to know the object's fully qualified type?

IE:

```
Implementation imp = new Implementation();
Stream inStream = Serialize(implementation);
IExample example = Deserialize(inStream);

example.foo();
```

This should print "This is an implementation!" to the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/775647

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15480780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is what I would recommend. Of course if you want to parse it as a type, you always need to know a type, but the JSON serializer is the best for what I think you need.

I would recommend using the DataContractJsonSerializer in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json as it is the most flexible in my experience.

Here is some additional helpful questions/articles about emitting and deserializing to types:
[when does DataContractJsonSerializer include the type information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887485/when-does-datacontractjsonserializer-include-the-type-information)

http://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/creating-net-objects-from-json-using-datacontractjsonserializer/

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to walk on shifting sands, which can be hard to manage in strictly typed languages.

If you have an object, try the approach of using the `as` keyword:

```
var example = Desrialize(inStream) as IExample;
if (example != null)
    example.foo();
```

The method I would use though would be to create a particular base object and implement IExample on that base, then when deserializing any object that extends it you can still cast them as the base object or as `IExample`. Alternatively, consider whether the polymorphism should take place in the `Deserialize()` method, either by overloading or by using generics.